# customize account setting with sync service

Tags: android, synchronization, accountmanager

I try to customize an account but I cannot found a solution to have what I want.

When I am in the account manager of android, I have several accounts for my application and I want to have specific settings for each account. I found solution to have global settings for the accounts (using the android:accountPreferences tag in the account description). But I was not able to have a specific information for one account. I was thinking to add preference after the synchronize option in the view for the account.
To precise, the place where I want to add my custom settings : 
[The list of account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyfHL.png) and the [account setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FT0i.png)

Comment: you can enable and disable sync by going into account section of settings menu.

Comment: Yes and I would like to have custom settings in the same page

Comment: click on that account you can manage settings there.

Comment: what about obvious choice like `AccountManager.setUserData`/`AccountManager.getUserData` ?

Comment: I really try to have user interface to have custom parameters

Comment: @Laurent92 did you solve it?